# JWT Authentication check and validate

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I have implemented JWT Auth in my project. JWT is generated by using below code (taking username and pass from user and finding it from Database) code below.

```java
public AuthenticateResponse Authenticate(AuthenticateRequest model)
    {
        var userres = new Users { Username = model.Username, Password = model.Password };
        var user = GetById(userres);

        // return null if user not found
        if (user == null) return null;

        // authentication successful so generate jwt token
        var token = generateJwtToken(user);

        return new AuthenticateResponse(user, token);
    }
private string generateJwtToken(Users user)
    {
        // generate token that is valid for 30 days
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("Username", user.Username.ToString()) }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

Next thing is that i am confused how can i Authenticate the generated JWT token each time user sends me to get access to the API's. How to implement that and how it's work? i have found many solutions but i am confused how they are validating this key?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the authorization header to request headers on client side and then you can parse the token to get what you want (id ,username etc.).

Comment: no i want to validate the token when ever from Client side the user sends me the token after login. how can i validate the token that it's generated from my web api.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to validate a token

```
var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_tokenManagement.Secret));

var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
ValidateAudience = false, //you might want to validate the audience and issuer depending on your use case
ValidateIssuer = false,
ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
ValidateLifetime = false //here we are saying that we don't care about the token's expiration date
};

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
SecurityToken securityToken;
var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out securityToken);

var jwtSecurityToken = securityToken as JwtSecurityToken;

if (jwtSecurityToken == null || !jwtSecurityToken.Header.Alg.Equals(SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
throw new SecurityTokenException("Invalid token");

return principal;
```